# Multi select returns an array but not a nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used multi-select for selecting multiple users here. what I have implemented:-

```
f.fields_for :user_id do r

  r.label :email  
      r.collection_select(:User.all, :id, :email, {:prompt => "select email", multiple: true})
```

It worked fine and I am able to select multiple users email

But it returns params as

```
 table_attributes => {0 => 
 {user_id: ["",1,2,3] } }
```

Since I am using `has_many` association so what I want is to get params as nested params like below:-

```
Table_attributes=>{0 => {user_id: 1}, 1 => {user_id: 2}, 2 => {user_id: 3}}
```

Can anyone explain how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Harsh, welcome to stackoverflow. I doubt rails would return the data in that format by default however you can always manipulate the params in controller once received. Also, could you tell me why do you need params to be in that specific format?

Comment: Hii Abhinay, thanks for the quick response,  I have used nested attributes(has_many association), I have a "abc table" that contains user_id type integer, I implemented a nested form where a user can select multiple emails and after submit ids will be sent as a Params but in a form of array, I want that if user select multiple emails there ( i.e=> (1,2,3) Ids will be selected ) then multiple records( in our case 3 records) should be saved as a different row in abc table.

Comment: For example:- if I have selected three emails(three user Ids will be sent), then I should be able to  save it in "abc table" like:-.                                        Id = 1. user_ Id = 1.                                            Id = 2. user_ Id = 2.                                           Id = 3. user_ Id = 3.

Comment: But saving multiple records in a table has very little to do with how params structure looks like. You can always iterate over an array to create the record one at a time Or use bulk insert